# CSS Shapes and shape-outside

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am using Chrome and Safari, in neither of them the attribute `shape-outside` seems to work. I've put both the `-webkit` and the normal version.

```css
.circle {
  background-color: #f3a57b;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  -webkit-shape-outside: circle(50%);
  float: left;
}
.text {
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
<p class="text">Some Text Here</p>
```

I want to get the text to adapt to the circle like this:http://codepen.io/adobe/pen/Cnvuf

Comment: ok..but what is the question?

Comment: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you want to make shape-outside work in all browsers. is that the question?

Comment: Check if  `shape-outside` in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside works correctly in your browser.

Comment: It's hard to reply when we don't know what you want to achieve. I suggest  you, as specific as possible, describe what you want to achieve and how the code you provided differs from that,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove `float:left` from `.text`, you'll see that it works:

```css
.circle {
    background-color: #f3a57b;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    -webkit-shape-outside: circle(50%);
    shape-outside: circle(50%);
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <p>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem</p>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ct7zeu8t/2)

---

As for Firefox and IE, [it's not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside#Browser_compatibility) (**Note:** Safari version 8.0).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-shapes), Safari doesn't support this feature. And chrome only support it with the 'experimental Web Platform features' enabled.

And I think you can enable this only with Chrome canary.